# Multiple bootstrap accordion panels - only one open at a time

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-accordion

I'm trying to figure out why my bootstrap accordions won't collapse when another has been opened. I coded it two separate way based on other stackoverflow examples I've seen, as well as bootstrap's docs and I still can't figure out why it's not functioning properly. Bootstrap JS is 3.3.7

The idea is that despite whatever `<a class="button collapsed">` is clicked, only that content is displayed, the rest should hide.

Example 1 uses separate panel groups

[js fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b65uLu7c/)

```
<div data-quickedit-entity-id="paragraph/84" class="panel-group" id="accordion-84" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" data-quickedit-entity-instance-id="0">
      <div class="panel panel-default consortia">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-abc">
          <div class="row panel-title">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-offset-130">

              <a class="button collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion-84" href="#abc-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="abc-1">btn1
                    </a>
              <a class="button collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion-84" href="#abc-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="abc-2">btn2
                    </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="abc-1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-abc" style="height: 1px;" aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="panel-body">
            test2
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="abc-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-abc" style="height: 1px;" aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="panel-body">
    test3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div data-quickedit-entity-id="paragraph/87" class="panel-group" id="accordion-87" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" data-quickedit-entity-instance-id="0">
      <div class="panel panel-default consortia">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-def">
          <div class="row panel-title">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-offset-130">
              <a class="button collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion-87" href="#def-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="def-1">btn1
                    </a>
              <a class="button collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion-87" href="#def-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="def-2">btn2
                    </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="def-1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-def">
          <div class="panel-body">
            test

          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="def-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-def">
          <div class="panel-body">
    test2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Example 2 uses the same panel-group

[js fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fw7c74f6/)

```
<div data-quickedit-entity-id="paragraph/90" class="panel-group" id="accordion-90" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" data-quickedit-entity-instance-id="0">
      <div class="panel panel-default consortia">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-tes">
          <div class="row panel-title">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-offset-130">
              <a class="button collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion-90" href="#tes-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="tes-1">btn1
                    </a>
              <a class="button collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion-90" href="#tes-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="tes-2">btn2
                    </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tes-1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-tes" style="height: 1px;" aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>test1</p>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tes-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-tes" style="height: 1px;" aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>test2</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default consortia">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-test2">
          <div class="row panel-title">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-offset-130">
              <a class="button collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion-90" href="#test2-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="test2-1">btn1
                    </a>
              <a class="button collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion-90" href="#test2-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="test2-2">btn2
                    </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="test2-1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-test2"  aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>test21</p>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="test2-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-test2"  aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>test23</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should work as you would expect.

I think the reason it wasn't working before is because you didn't have the id selector in the "data-parent" attribute.

```
 <div data-quickedit-entity-id="paragraph/90" class="panel-group" id="accordion-90" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" data-quickedit-entity-instance-id="0">
      <div class="panel panel-default consortia">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-tes">
          <div class="row panel-title">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-offset-130">
              <a class="button collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-90" href="#tes-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="tes-1">btn1
                    </a>
              <a class="button collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-90" href="#tes-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="tes-2">btn2
                    </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tes-1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-tes" style="height: 1px;" aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>test1</p>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tes-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-tes" style="height: 1px;" aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>test2</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default consortia">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-test2">
          <div class="row panel-title">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-offset-130">
              <a class="button collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-90" href="#test2-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="test2-1">btn1
                    </a>
              <a class="button collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-90" href="#test2-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="test2-2">btn2
                    </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="test2-1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-test2"  aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>test21</p>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="test2-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-test2"  aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>test23</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This was exactly it. I was missing the "#" in the data-parent attribute. Thank you!